# Accidentally deleted EFI boot partition and reinstalled it can't boot into windows now

Tags: uefi

So I accidentally deleted EFI partition I created it again with Linux but now I am just unable to boot into Windows even when I try to change boot order or trying to manually select it in boot menu.

If anyone could help me would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to install the Windows bootloader, this is a Windows question.

Comment: Oh I will continue on the Microsoft forum if I'd face any issues with that, thanks for the help though!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)